# Google Drive & Spreadsheets API: Get the user's email address

Tags: javascript, api, spreadsheet, drive

I'm developing a simple CRUD website using the Google Drive and Spreadsheets API (javascript/jquery only), so the users who have access to the file can add or change some entries in a spreadsheet. 
That's all done, but now I need to get the user's email address so I can identify who's making changes.
Any idea of how to get that data?

Comment: Have you researched the API to see if that data is available somehow? What have you found so far? Have you tried any approaches before now?

Comment: can you share your code where you are getting problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution using the Google+ API...here it is:

```
function getEmail(){
 gapi.client.load('plus','v1', function(){
    var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
        'userId': 'me'
    });
    request.execute(function(resp) {
        console.log(resp.emails[0].value);
    });
 });
```

}